# why runtime error in this function c++ depth first search?

Tags: c++, c++11

why this function get runtime error
what is the wrong with it?

```
void dfs(int node){
  visited[node]=true;
  for(int i=1;i<=arr[node].size();i++){
   int child=arr[node][i];
   if(!visited[child]){
    dfs(child);
   }
  }
}
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: 1) Did you try to step through your code with a debugger? 2) Please provide [mcve].

Comment: the program stop suddenly

Comment: `for(int i=1;i<=arr[node].size();i++)` looks unusual. It skips the first element and appears to run one past the end. I would expect to see `for(int i=0;i<arr[node].size();i++)`

Comment: Stop fighting zero-based indexing. The sooner you get over that hump the better your C or C++ life will be.

Comment: Please show us your error.

Comment: yes but still runtime error

Comment: This wouldn't happen with a range-based for loop. It's not too often that actual indices are needed.

Comment: this is my error when i try to call function Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

Comment: Do not assume that a program has only one fatal error. Fixing bug N may reveal bug N+1 to you.

Comment: @Yazan [Edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48103697/edit). It should contain *all* relevant code required to reproduce the problem, and *exact*, complete error messaging as delivered to you.

Comment: @Yazan If you made a mistake with the 1-based indexing, you're probably making similar mistakes in other parts of your code.  For example, what is `visited` and what is `node`?  Is `visited` an array and `node` also suffers from being a 1-based value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't show all the needed code but I'm just going to guess you forgot arrays and containers are 0-index-based in C++ (change `1` to `0` and `<=` to `<`):

```
for(int i = 0;i < arr[node].size();i++){
```